# Кириллица, GitHub и кодировки

Tags: c, github, utf-8, ansi

Подскажите, что необходимо сделать, чтобы кириллица в текстовых исходниках на сайте **GitHub** отображалась корректно? Проблема восьмибитных кодировок, по всей видимости, связана в тем, что сам просмотрщик исходников на **GitHub** неверно интерпретирует кодовую страницу.

Одно из возможных решений - сохранять исходники в **UTF-8**. Оно работает, кириллица на **GitHub** отображается корректно, но у такого решения есть минус: после сборки программы из исходников в **UTF-8** (**Язык C**, **Code::Blocks**, **WinGW 32**, **Windows 10**) кириллица в консоли отображается неверно. И дело не в **setlocale()**, **SetConsoleCP()** и **SetConsoleOutputCP()**.

Я пробовал разные кодовые страницу (**866**, **1251** и пр.) - проблема с отображением кириллицы в программе, которая собрана из исходников в **UTF-8**, не решается.

Каждый раз при загрузке исходников на **GitHub** делать **ANSI->UTF-8**, и при каждом скачивании исходников с **GitHub** делать **UTF-8->ANSI**, неудобно.

Или, может, возможно настроить **Code::Blocks**, чтобы он использовал исходники в **UTF-8**, но при этом верно формировал кириллические символы (для строковых/символьных литералов)?

С каким бубном и как правильно нужно попрыгать?

Comment: Перед выводом на печать, строки можно перекодировать в ANSI кодировку (см. [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272822)). Ну и, консоль Windows можно настроить, чтобы она UTF-8 правильно отображала (см. [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38694885))

Comment: А на самом GitHub нет какого-нибудь способа задать кодировку, в которой необходимо отображать однобайтовую кодировку исходника?

Comment: Относительно перекодирования строк перед выводом на печать - этот вариант слишком громоздок и сложен. К тому же, я полагаю, что строковые кириллические литералы все равно будут однобайтовые, даже если исходник представлен в UTF-8.

Comment: Не правильно полагаете, будет в той кодировке, что и исходник, т.е. в utf-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC умеет при компиляции менять кодировку всех строк в программе, так что можете хранить код в той кодировке, которая больше нравится.

Для этого используются следующие флаги:

```
-finput-charset=ИсходнаяКодировка -fexec-charset=ЖелаемаяКодирвока
```

Например, преобразование из UTF8 в CP866 делается вот так:

```
-finput-charset=utf-8 -fexec-charset=cp866
```

---

В CodeBlocks эти флаги нужно вписать в "Прочие опции компилятора" в настройках проекта.

Comment: Сработало, большое спасибо! Теперь кириллица выводиться даже без setlocale() и пр.!

Comment: Что конкретно при этом происходит? Если полученный exe будет запускаться на "левой" системе, в которой, допустим, установлена не русскоязычная локаль?

Comment: @Максим На левой системе будут кракозябры, т.к. в программе (в .exe) строки будут закодированы в cp866 (или какую вы там задали). Если хотите сделать вывод нормально на любой системе, то вам надо всё делать руками: хранить строки в utf8, при печати строк определять системную кодировку и конвертировать строки в неё. Пример, как это делается под Windows, я давал в первой ссылке в комментарии к вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, что необходимо сделать, чтобы кириллица в текстовых исходниках на сайте GitHub и в консоли Visual Studio отображалась корректно?

При использовании Visual Studio 2022 для написания консольных приложений необходимо кодировку файла поставить `UTF-8` и включить `system("chcp 1251")` в функцию `main`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    cout << endl;
    int count = 7;
    float avgWeight = 155.5F;
    double totalWeight = count * avgWeight;
    cout << "Вес равен " << totalWeight << endl;
    return 0;
    //aCharVar = static_cast<char>(anIntVar);

}
```

Так в консоли и в GitHub русские символы будут выводиться правильно.